# How to exclude records in select query for tableA where tableA.user_id does not exist in user.id

Tags: mysql

I want to select records ( pm's ) but exclude id's (sender) of deleted accounts that do not exists in users table anymore ( deleted )

This is for a "new message" notification

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(pm.id) c
                FROM `private_messages` pm
                LEFT JOIN `users` u ON u.`id` = pm.`sender_id`
                WHERE pm.`recipient_id` = '".$user_id."'
                AND (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `pm_views` WHERE `user_id` = '".$user_id."' AND `message_id` = pm.id) = 0
            ";
```

TABLES:

```
private_messages = id, recipient_id, sender_id, date_sent.
pm_views = id, message_id, view_date, user_id
```

the above sql returns count of "unviewed" messages.

I want to exclude messages from non existant ID's from users table.

Comment: this worked for me `AND u.id IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gather you have 3 tables here: users, private_messages and pm_views. Where pm_views contains a record for every "view"(A user opened a private message).

Hopefully I have this right: the query you're looking for will count every message to a specific user that has not been viewed yet by that user, but will not include unviewed messages from users who no longer exist in the users table.

I do believe this could be done with subqueries as follows:

```
select  count(*)
from    private_messages pm
where   pm.recipient_id = '" . $user_id . "'
        and pm.id not in (
            select  message_id
            from    pm_views
        )
        and pm.sender_id in (
            select  id
            from    users
        )
```

Comment: ah yes .. this works perfectly. thank you. my own answer below worked aswell but I cudnt figure out why, I understand why it works in your answer ,the lights went on :)

Answer (score -1):

Adding this works

```
AND u.id IS NOT NULL
```

Final query

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(pm.id) c
                FROM `private_messages` pm
                LEFT JOIN `users` u ON u.`id` = pm.`sender_id`
                WHERE pm.`recipient_id` = '".$user_id."'
                AND u.id IS NOT NULL
                AND (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `pm_views` WHERE `user_id` = '".$user_id."' AND `message_id` = pm.id) = 0
            ";
```